# Getting pages by url using Wordpress REST API

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, api, rest, routes

I'm attempting to using WP REST API on a site that uses pretty URLs, not ID's (which is typical in a REST scenario). All I have to query with is the requested URL.

Lets say a user lands on `example.com/about`, I can do the following:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/?slug=about
```

No sweat. However, what if a users lands on `example.com/about/team`? I *could* query by the slug `team`, but maybe my site also has `example.com/contact/team` as a possible URL. It's not reliable.

What I need is a way of achieving the following:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/?permalink=about%2team
```

It's unfeasible to have to set up custom routes for each page that gets created. I'm surprised the API doesn't appear to have some kind of permalink handler out of the box.

Comment: I'd also like to have an answer for this exact issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo I've also stumbled upon this one in one of my projects. Check out my answer, that might help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since there is no tool to handle all of the cases, you have to be a bit crafty. It is possible to use a combination of wp functions like `url_to_postid` or `get_term_by` and global variables like `$wp_taxonomies` to figure out all of the cases.

You can create a custom endpoint and use the code below to handle the path. I think that I have covered all of the possible cases, but use carefully cause I might miss something.

```
function ca_path_to_object($path = '/') {
    $path = $path === '/' ? $path : trim($path, '/');
    $path = $path === '' ? '/' : $path; // Return homepage for no arguments
    $for_front = intval(get_option('page_on_front'));
    $for_posts = intval(get_option( 'page_for_posts' ));
    if($path == '/') $pid = $for_front; // It is the homepage
    else $pid = url_to_postid($path); // It is not
    if($for_posts != 0) { //For some reason url_to_postid does not work if the page is set to be the blog feed
        if($for_posts == $for_front) { // if both $for_front & $for_posts set to the same page get_permalink returns 404 for some reason, so lets construct it manually
            $pst = get_post($for_posts);
            $prnt = intval($pst->post_parent);
            $url = '';
            if($prnt != 0) {
                $url = parse_url(get_permalink($prnt));
                $url = trim($url['path'], '/');
            }
            $url .= '/'.$pst->post_name;
            // if it matches it will return the results as Homepage as per default WP behaviour
        }
        else {
            $url = parse_url(get_permalink($for_posts)); // otherwise just get it
            $url = $url['path'];
        }
        if(trim($url, '/') == $path) $pid = $for_posts;
    }
    if($pid == 0) { // not a page or cpt, let's try to find a taxonomy out of it
        $path_arr = explode('/', $path);
        global $wp_taxonomies;
        $tax = null;
        foreach ($wp_taxonomies as $key => $value) {
            if ($value->rewrite['slug'] === $path_arr[0]){
                $tax = $key;
            }
        }
        if($tax !== null) {
            $term = get_term_by('slug', end($path_arr), $tax);
            if($term !== false) {
                $pid = $term->term_id;
                return array(
                    'type' => 'term',
                    'id' => $term->term_id,
                    'object' => $term,
                );
            }
        }
    }
    if($pid == 0) { // If still 0, perhaps it's an user profile url?
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $base = explode('/', trim($wp_rewrite->get_author_permastruct(), '/'));
        $base = $base[0];
        if($path_arr[0] === $base) {
            $user = get_user_by('slug', end($path_arr));
            if($user !== false) {
                $pid = $user->ID;
                return array(
                    'type' => 'user',
                    'id' => $user->ID,
                    'object' => $user,
                );
            }
        }
    }
    if(($pid == 0) && ($path == '/')) { // If still 0, lets check if the page is the homepage without any associated page entity
        return array(
            'type' => 'home',
            'id' => null,
            'object' => null,
        );
    }
    if($pid == 0) { // If still 0, return nothing found or 404
        return array(
            'type' => '404',
            'id' => null,
            'object' => null,
        );
    }
    $post = get_post($pid);
    if($post->ID == $for_front) { // It's a page assigned to be a homepage
        return array(
            'type' => 'home',
            'id' => $post->ID,
            'object' => $post,
        );
    }
    if($post->ID == $for_posts) { // It's a page assigned to be a posts feed
        return array(
            'type' => 'feed',
            'id' => $post->ID,
            'object' => $post,
        );
    }
    return array( // It's just a post object
        'type' => 'post',
        'id' => $post->ID,
        'object' => $post,
    );
}
```